# 'Virgin' is to 'Virginity as 'Vegan' is to ____?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the equivalent form of *vegan* that matches *virginity*?

My only thoughts are *veganity*, which doesn't appear to be a word, or *veganism*, which doesn't seem to be exactly equivalent.

What word should fit here?

Example Sentence:

> My [veganity] is very important to me.

Comment: Please follow the checklist in the tag info. You must include a sample sentence and why you rejected any words you have (Why is *veganism* wrong?)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Of course, sorry, example added in.

Comment: And what do you intend it to mean? And why isn't *veganism* suitable? C'mon, you've been here long enough. Set a good example.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Fair enough. I just haven't heard *veganism* as a word. I've accepted the answer so the question should go away

Comment: And why isn't 'vegetarianism' good enough?

Comment: @Mitch Because that is a different concept; vegans don't eat eggs, milk or *any*animal products, while vegetarians merely don't eat meat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for ***[veganism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism)*** which is:

> both the practice of abstaining from the use of animal products, particularly in diet, and an associated abolitionist philosophy that rejects the commodity status of animals.A follower of either the diet or the philosophy is known as a vegan (pronounced vee-gən).

Wikipedia

The term has been increasingly used from the '70s according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=veganism&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cveganism%3B%2Cc0).

[Vegan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vegan):

> - ***1944, from vegetable (n.) + -an; coined by English vegetarian Donald Watson*** (1910-2005) to distinguish those who abstain from all animal products (eggs, cheese, etc.) from those who merely refuse to eat the animals. (Etymonline)

The noun form veganism is from ***vegan + [ism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ism):***

> - used to form nouns that refer to social, political, or religious beliefs, studies, or ways of behaving: like 
>     *sexism
>     feminism
>     Buddhism* (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Yes. The OED recognises *veganism* as it does *vegetarianism*, and has no record of *veganity*.

Comment: So do other more readily available sources. This question is genref.